# How to place signature image at the bottom of pdf page in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I upload the pdf file from storage.
I'm trying to place the signature image at the bottom of every single page of pdf file and save as new pdf file using flutter.

---

I don't know how to do that? I tried my sample but I didn't find the solution I wanted. Please suggest me any flutter plugins or packages.

Comment: Did you find solution?

Answer (score 0):

> The idea is very simple: it consists of reading the pdf file as images
> (one image per page), and then create a pdf, having as background one
> of the retrieved images.

this [article](https://medium.com/flutter-community/edit-a-pdf-in-flutter-6a80f8aa7dfd) explains what u need

https://medium.com/flutter-community/edit-a-pdf-in-flutter-6a80f8aa7dfd